# Best way to create a Promise from synchronous code?

Tags: javascript, promise

Let's say I have a synchronous function, `foo()`, that returns some result.  Does it make any significant difference if I go

```
return Promise.resolve(foo());    // code runs within Promise.resolve
```

vs.

```
var result = foo();               // code runs outside of any Promise stuff
return Promise.resolve(result);
```

Comment: Obviously I hit the wrong button before completing the question.  Geez guys, 4 downvotes in 3 minutes for that?

Comment: Notice that `Promise.resolve` is in itself just another synchronous function, and it does not make any difference regardless of what functions you are calling there with or without an intermediate variable. I guess you have a severe misunderstanding of promises, can you elaborate what you mean by "*code runs within Promise.resolve*"?

Comment: @Bergi wouldn't say I _misunderstand_ Promises, just lack of understanding of some of the subtleties.  :-)  Your answer is excellent, pointing out that `Promise.resolve()` is _itself synchronous_ really clarifies things.  You might want to make that a "real" answer.

Comment: I'm not sure what else you think it did? But probably it's not just a subtlety.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does it make any significant difference

No.

In one case you save the result of `foo()` to a variable. This could be useful if you need to use it for something else, or if the multi-line nature and named variable makes a complicated piece of code easier to understand. In the other case, `foo()` is still generating a return value, you're just not saving a reference to it. If you don't need to use it anywhere else, and you think the code is understandable on its own, this is fine too.